# dual screen support for plasma desktop

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, arch-linux, xorg, kde

I have 2 displays with differing resolutions, and have them mostly working on a Garuda Linux dr460nized version (KDE Plasma). My current xrandr configuration is:

`[ 2 -eq $(xrandr |grep -c 'DP') ] && xrandr --dpi 280 --fb 7680x4320 --output eDP-1 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0; xrandr --output DP-1 --scale 2x2 --pos 3840x0 --panning 3840x2160+3840+0`

I run this script when I bring up the first terminal window. The difficulty is that the desktop background and the menu bar at the screen top display only in the top 1/4 of the second monitor. Everything else is as desired; is there any way to get the background and menu bar to display correctly on the second screen? (Somehow the Cinnamon desktop has worked around this problem).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like the desktop background and menu bar at the top of the screen to be full screen on the secondary monitor. It currently only occupies 1/4 of the screen, although all applications etc. utilize the full screen and are scaled appropriately to be roughly the same size as on the primary display (proportional to the monitor's physical dimensions).